# Не добавляется telebot python. В группу. Telegram

Tags: python, telebot

Вот видео: https://youtu.be/InQc54fG_o0 Там видно что не заходит бот, как это можно решить, об ошибке сообщения никакого нету со стороны телеграм, а все разрешения я включил. Может поможет доп инфа что я являюсь только администратором группы.